# when button is disable then also on click event call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

once the button clicked I have a disabled button and on page load, I get the status of the button and then enable and disable the button according to requirement.it's work properly but I give an on-click event to the button. when the button is disabled then also when I click the button javascript call a method.

i have  tag as a button.
how I can handle when button is disabled raise event stop.

thank you in advance.

```
<a id="check_status_api" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0)">run_batch</a>

$("#check_status_api").click(function(e){
  console.log('my ajax call code ')
})

$(document).ready(function(){
  //on page load get status of my batch if it's running then button disable property add 
    if ('runnig' == 'runnig'){
      $("#check_status_api").attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
    }
    
})
```

Comment: You can't use the `disabled` attribute in this way, because disabled elements do not raise any events.

Comment: link is disabled then also element raise events. @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
const myBtn = $('#check_status_api')

myBtn.click(function(e){
    if (!myBtn.is('[disabled=disabled]')) {
        console.log('my ajax call code ')
  }
})

$(document).ready(function(){
  //on page load get status of my batch if it's running then button disable property add 
    if ('runnig' == 'runnig'){
      myBtn.attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="check_status_api" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0)">run_batch</a>
```

Comment: I have <a> tag not button so for this it's not works

Comment: I find one solution for <a> tag  replace !myBtn.is(':disabled') with { !$('#check_status_api').is('[disabled=disabled]') } it's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("btn btn-info btn-sm").prop('disabled', true);
```

or you can try adding a css class on click that disables the button:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

or `document.getElementById("check_status_api").disabled = true;`

Comment: I have <a> tag as a button so this not works for <a> tag $('#check_status_api').is('[disabled=disabled]') this works for me. thank you.